# Everify and employers who hire OPT students

Tags: usa

I am an F-1 Visa holder under OPT. I have received a job offer from an employer who does not appear to participate in E-verify (company name not in E-Verify Employers Search Tool on uscis.gov website). What does this mean for me as a prospective employee? Does this mean I cannot work for this employer? Does it mean the employer needs to enroll in E-Verify? I am very new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work for any employer for regular (12-month) OPT. It's only for the additional 17-month STEM OPT extension that the employer needs E-Verify.